Why /usr/include is missing when I compile in a gitlab pipeline
I'm trying to build a c++ app with cmake in a gitlab pipeline. The project compiles on my local machine, but fails in the pipeline because it can't find a header file that's in /usr/include. I confirmed with an ls that the header file is in /usr/include in the pipeline. I have the following include directories specified in my CMakeLists.txt file.
include_directories(
       /usr/include
       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test/inc)

The pipeline fails because it can't find the header file. When I added --verbose to the cmake command, I noticed that /usr/include doesn't appear when c++ is executed. I see -I/builds/.../inc and -I/builds/.../test/inc but not -I/usr/include. Does anyone know why /usr/include is missing when c++ runs in the gitlab pipeline?

And what header file can't be find?

@273K can't find zmq.h

CMake thinks that /usr/include is an implicit include directory for your compiler, so the directory is not passed as a parameter for the compiler. See e.g. that question.
